# SqlDeveloper - checking for NULL values without IS NULL clause - in a scripted query

Tags: python, sql, oracle, null

```
for circuit in allCircuit:                   # a cvs of 4 columns

    part = circuit.split(",")
    
    res = cur.execute("""SELECT col4 from ATable WHERE
    ( "col1" = :a
    AND "col2" = :b
    AND "col3" = :c
    AND "col4" = :d) 
    ORDER BY col4""",a = part[0], b= part[1], c = part[2], d = part[3])
```

part[0] through part[3] may contain NULL (typed) values.

But Oracle doesn't accept a where clause like:

WHERE "col1" = NULL

## WRONG

WHERE "col1" IS NULL

## RIGHT

How do I put "IS NULL" stmt in my scripted query instead of "col = NULL" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle **null is not equal null**
You can use in your query

```
... and decode( col1, :a, 1, 0 )=1
```

or

```
... and (col1=:a or (col1 is null and :a is null))
```